# Files built with a makefile are disapearing (including the binary)

Tags: linux, debian, make, makefile, single-board

I am building a program on a TS-7800(SBC), and when I run make (show below), it appears to go through all of the steps normally, but in the end i do not get a binary file. Why is this, and how can I get my file.

makefile

```
CC= /home/eclipse/ReidTest/cc/cross-toolchains/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc 

# compiler options

#CFLAGS= -O2
CFLAGS= -mcpu=arm9 
#CFLAGS= -pg -Wall

# linker

LN= $(CC)

# linker options

LNFLAGS= 
#LNFLAGS= -pg

# extra libraries used in linking (use -l command)

LDLIBS= -lpthread

# source files

SOURCES= HMITelem.c Cpacket.c GPS.c ADC.c Wireless.c Receivers.c CSVReader.c RPM.c RS485.c

# include files

INCLUDES= Cpacket.h HMITelem.h CSVReader.h RS485.h

# object files

OBJECTS= HMITelem.o Cpacket.o GPS.o ADC.o Wireless.o Receivers.o CSVReader.o RPM.o RS485.o

HMITelem: $(OBJECTS)
    $(LN) $(LNFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LDLIBS)

.c.o:   $*.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $*.c

RUN : ./HMITelem

#clean:
#   rm -f *.o
#   rm -f *~
```

Output

```
root@ts7800:ReidTest# make
/home/eclipse/ReidTest/cc/cross-toolchains/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mcpu=arm9  -c HMITelem.c
/home/eclipse/ReidTest/cc/cross-toolchains/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mcpu=arm9  -c Cpacket.c
/home/eclipse/ReidTest/cc/cross-toolchains/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mcpu=arm9  -c GPS.c
/home/eclipse/ReidTest/cc/cross-toolchains/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mcpu=arm9  -c ADC.c
/home/eclipse/ReidTest/cc/cross-toolchains/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mcpu=arm9  -c Wireless.c
/home/eclipse/ReidTest/cc/cross-toolchains/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mcpu=arm9  -c Receivers.c
/home/eclipse/ReidTest/cc/cross-toolchains/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mcpu=arm9  -c CSVReader.c
/home/eclipse/ReidTest/cc/cross-toolchains/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mcpu=arm9  -c RPM.c
/home/eclipse/ReidTest/cc/cross-toolchains/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mcpu=arm9  -c RS485.c
/home/eclipse/ReidTest/cc/cross-toolchains/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc   -o HMITelem HMITelem.o Cpacket.o GPS.o ADC.o Wireless.o Receivers.o CSVReader.o RPM.o RS485.o -lpthread
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implicit *make* rule for compiling a source into an object file seems broken. There's no output specification "-o x.o" to go with the "cc -c x.c". Are there any object files after running the make?

```
.c.o:   $*.c
```

Also, the above target specification, ".c.o", looks strange to me; perhaps *make* does not recognize this either, and that would explain why the implicit rule for making an object file is not being applied.

This might be a better target specification and prerequisites for the objects rule (straight from the GNU 'make' manual):

```
$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.c
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use `>` for quoting code, instead indent with 4 spaces.

Comment: That worked!!!!

Answer (score 0):

.c.o is only special (a suffix rule) if it has no prerequisites, in which case each .c file is an implicit prerequisite of the corresponding .o file. If it has a prerequisite, make tries to build a file named .c.o! See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html